# Selecting country names based on country codes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `users` which has a column `codecountry` and another table called `country` which has columns `code` and `country`.

I want to select the `country` from table `country` based on the `codecountry` from table `users`.

I thought the code below would work but it always returns an empty set and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Code:

```
SELECT country 
FROM country 
WHERE (code) IN (
    SELECT codecountry 
    FROM users 
    WHERE  iduser="me"
)
```

Comment: The problem is probably `iduser = "me"`.  If nothing matches, you'll get nothing returned.

Comment: `"me"` should be `'me'`. Double quotes are for alias names; single quotes are for string literals. Then there is a closing parenthesis missing.

Comment: Now see about JOINs

Comment: @Strawberry: What does the question have to do with joins? The task is to get data from the country table where the code matches an entry in the users table. An `IN` clause is perfectly okay for this. (Better would be a simple `=` instead of course, as the subquery is supposed to return one row only.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You cannot be serious. Obviously, a JOIN is the appropriate solution here.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `IN()` , `EXISTS()` or any other variation of a solution with a  join. They exists for a reason .

Comment: There is nothing wrong with IN or EXISTS, but JOINs are the fundamental building blocks of SQL. It would serve the OP well to get to grips with them before exploring other avenues. It's preposterous to suggest that a JOIN is somehow inappropriate here.

Comment: I don't think Throsten suggested its inappropriate in anyway , I think his  intention was to state that there is nothing wrong with `IN()` . @Strawberry

Comment: I think @Strawberry meant to say, "a JOIN is an appropriate solution here". I would be less inclined to use a join because only one column from one table is being projected in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.country
  FROM country c
  JOIN users u
    ON u.codecountry = c.code
 WHERE u.iduser = "me";
```

Comment: If you want to join the user "me", then why isn't this condition part of the join criteria (i.e. `ON` clause)? BTW: the use of non-standard string delimiters should not be encouraged.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yep. That's fine too - better even. Fill your boots.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: But move the `u.codecountry = c.code` to the `WHERE`  clause and you'd get told off :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problems is with `"me"` , strings should be wrapped with single quotes , also , try using backticks for reserved words (which normally throws an error) :

```
SELECT country
FROM country
WHERE`code IN (SELECT codecountry
               FROM `users`
               WHERE  iduser='me')
```

Either that, or as @GordonLinoff said in the comments, maybe no record match this condition on `users` table.

Comment: This is not really an answer. Are you saying for example that the OP's query fails because they use `(code)` rather than ` `code` `? (Sorry, I don't know how to place the backticks in a comment, but you know what I mean.)

Comment: Sorry, had a thing to do so I didn't add any explanation. Actually I just added it since it's a reserved word, but I think the problem is with the double quotes. @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Ah, that looks better :-) I didn't even know that `code` is a reserved word in MySQL.

Comment: It's a reserved word in Oracle :P I didn't actually check if it's in MySQL as well.

Comment: No, in Oracle it isn't (`select * from v$reserved_words where keyword = 'CODE'` returns no rows). And I just looked up https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html. `code` is a keyword in MySQL which is not reserved and can thus be used as a column name without backticks or double quotes. :-)

Comment: Huh, PLSQL Developer marked the word for me like it's reserved, so I assumed it is :P @ThorstenKettner